# SagePay Test transactions are always Pending, say Failed in MySagePay

Tags: php, opayo, protx, pending-transition

I've integrated SagePay Server using a PHP Library https://github.com/academe/SagePay

I'm running on their Test mode using their test card details.

Every transaction I put through comes back with a status of PENDING, my understanding is that when this happens the callback URL will be hit again with an OK when the payment has gone through.

In MySagePay the transactions are marked as FAILED, but there are no details as to why they failed.

How can I find out why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted SagePay and they provided me with some excellent logs of what our systems were sending and receiving. The issue, in my case, was an un-writable database causing an exception to be thrown at my NotificationURL.

To answer the question, as Pekka said, Contact them.

In the mean time, check your NotificationURL isn't throwing errors.